# Trigger an Insert in another table when i insert a value on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table that I log the status from some services.

I need to trigger an insert in another table when this table `A` receive one insert with the value `FALSE`.

Let me try to explain a little more:

I Have one table `EMAIL` into which I insert emails that I want to send. I Have another table `LOG` that logs one service. If the table `LOG` receives one insert on field `STATUS` with the value `FALSE` I want to trigger one insert in the table `EMAIL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Try this...........

```
-------------Sample Table

create table [log] (Id int,[status] varchar(10))
create table Email ([Status] varchar(10),id int)

go

------------ Trigger Creation

  create trigger tri_log on log
for insert 
as

insert into email(id,[status])
select a.[id],a.[status] 
from inserted a where a.[status] = 'false'

go

------------------Sample Check

select * from [log]
select * from [email]

-----------insert records for test

insert into [log] values (1,'True')
insert into [log] values (2,'False')

----------verify result
select * from [log]
select * from [email]
```

Comment: This will fail when inserting more than 1 row: insert into [log] values (1,'True'),(4,'false')

Comment: @ t.clausen tanks for the comment and i have edited the trigger and i think this will work good for multiple rows.

Comment: Yes, it also fixes a different issue +1